# Using J library with AMD modules project instead of commonJS

Tags: typescript

I was able to use this library in a Nodejs application https://github.com/SheetJS/j but I can't seem to get it working in a new project where I need to use amd modules.

With commonjs I was able to do:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/j/misc/j.d.ts"/>
var Excel = <J>require('J');
```

Latest attempt with AMD I am trying:

```
/// <amd-dependency path = "../../j/j" /> (the Library is in a different spot in this project)
private run(){
    var Excel = require('../../j/j');
    var array = Excel.readFile("D:\\file.xls");
}
```

error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'require'.
This is based of watching this I think this J library knows about exports but I could be wrong? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA

EDIT:

```
///<reference path='misc/cfb.d.ts'/>

interface Cell {
    v;
    w;
    t: string;
    f: string;
    ixfe: number;
}

interface CellAddress {
    c: number;
    r: number;
}

interface CellRange {
    s: CellAddress;
    e: CellAddress;
}


interface Worksheet {
    [key: string]: Cell;
}

interface Worksheets {
    [key: string]: Worksheet;
}

interface Workbook {
    SheetNames: string[];
    Sheets: Worksheets;
}

interface J {
    parse_xlscfb(cfb:CFBContainer): Workbook;
    read;
    readFile(filename:string): any;
    utils: {
        encode_col(col:number): string;
        encode_row(row:number): string;
        encode_cell(cell:CellAddress): string;
        encode_range;
        decode_col(col:string): number;
        decode_row(row:string): number;
        split_cell(cell:string): string[];
        decode_cell(cell:string): CellAddress;
        decode_range(cell:string): CellRange;
        sheet_to_csv(worksheet:Worksheet): string;
        get_formulae(worksheet:Worksheet): string[];
        make_csv(worksheet:Worksheet): string;
        sheet_to_row_object_array(worksheet:Worksheet): Object[];
    };
    verbose: Number;
    CFB: CFB;
    main;
}
```

Edit Tried answer:
Tried adding module to top of d.ts file

```
///<reference path='misc/cfb.d.ts'/>

declare module 'J'{
    var j: J;
    export = j;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting `j.d.ts` from? You should update it to include:

```
declare module 'J'{
    var j:J;
    export = j; 
}
```

Then you can do :

```
import Excel = require('J');
```

Notice *import* instead of *var*. This way you can compile with `--module commonjs` for node and `--module amd` for requirejs.

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: One of the libraries it included has a d.ts I think I changed it a little.  I will try ur suggestion

Comment: I posted my d.ts I I still curious why it didn't just work in the first place.  I watched you video and it sound like the different modules are supposed to be compatible. (Thanks)